# phone call made it past work focus - "allow calls from allowed people only" with no allowed people

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, focus

I have an iPhone 11 with iOS 16.2. I have it scheduled to be in work focus mode every weekday from 9 am to 5 pm.

Today in the morning at 11 am, I could clearly see the "work focus" icon on my home screen. I was working at my desk in the office, and got a call from a family member, **and my phone rang, which is surprising, since it should not have.**

In the "work focus" settings, I have "allow calls from" set to "allowed people only" (**not** favorites), and my "allowed people" list is completely empty.

Anyone else experience this or know of any active bug reports?

(I've also repeatedly, more than 10 instances over many months, experienced a similar bug when my iPhone is connected to my Tesla model Y thru Bluetooth, and even though the iPhone is in "Driving mode", calls go through to my car's speaker system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double-check the Allow Repeated Calls setting in the Allow Notifications → People section of the Focus settings. If enabled, a second call from the same person within 3 minutes, even not in the allowed list, will be allowed through.

Comment: I checked my call logs, and indeed when the behavior happened, there were two calls back-to-back from the same person.